# Redirect Error Messages for SFTP

Tags: linux, bash, sftp

I'm sftp to a server and I would like to download the files and all the info are redirected to a file.  I have a bash script to do this, and it works great but when I get error messages, for example, no file exists, it doesn't write the error messages to a file, instead it displays them on screen.  How do I write the error messages to a file?

I tried this but it made no difference

```
sftp -i id_rsa -P 22 root@myserver<<EOF >> output.log 2>> errfile.txt
```

Here's my code:

```
#!/bin/bash

sftp -i id_rsa -P 22 root@myserver<<EOF >> output.log 
get SomeFiles*
quit
EOF
```

This is what display on the screen if there are no files.

```
Connected to myserver.
File "/tmp/SomeFiles*" not found.
```

Is there a way to redirect all the error messages to file instead of having them display on a screen?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with SFTP errors. And the only working way (at least in my env: RHL7) was to execute sftp with batch file:

```
#!/bin/bash

log_file=output.log
err_file=errfile.txt

#redirect proc output to output.log 
exec >> $log_file

echo "get SomeFiles*" > /somefolder/sftp_batch.txt

#redirect sftp errors to errfile.txt
sftp -i id_rsa -P 22 -b /somefolder/sftp_batch.txt root@myserver 2>> $err_file
```

Or if you don't need to have the errors in a separate file it's possible to replace the last row:

```
sftp -i id_rsa -P 22 -b /somefolder/sftp_batch.txt root@myserver 2>> $err_file
```

with

```
sftp -i id_rsa -P 22 -b /somefolder/sftp_batch.txt root@myserver 2>> $log_file
```

then it writes proc output and sftp error messages to one file.